# Problem with installation

Tags: apt, xubuntu

when I run the command

```
sudo apt-get -f install ssl-cert
```

I am getting the result:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

And then when I run the command  **sudo dpkg --configure -a**, the result is:

```
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72) ...
Running depmod.
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72)update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
```

And it hangin there. And the CPU 100% all the time. My version is Xubuntu 16.04 with kernel:

> 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux